# Is it bad practice to duplicate data in JSON?

Tags: json

I'd like to store some data in a JSON object and am wondering if it's bad practice to store it in more than one place. Take for example a review site, in a relational database I might have a table for reviews and a table for users. I could connect the two using a join. My goal is to have a Movie page that holds all reviews for that movie and also have users who know about all of their reviews they've written.

```
{
  "reviews": {
    "movie1": [{
      "author": "user1",
      "review": "Some review..."
    }]
  },
  "users": [{
    "userName": "user1",
    "userReviews": [{
      "movie1": "Some review..."
    }]
  }]
}
```

Would keeping a reviews object with all reviews for that specific movie (and within each review, an author property) and also a users object with all of their reviews be a bad idea? Data would be duplicated, so wondering what the best way to approach this situation.

Thank you.

Comment: Is anything besides the keys ("movie1", "user1") being duplicated? If not, this seems perfectly fine. You can't really avoid duplicating keys.

Comment: This looks like JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: It would be the text of the entire review, along with probably 6-7 other properties (scores/rankings in the form of integers most likely).

Comment: @FelixKling It's very clearly JSON. See http://json.org.

Comment: @GregBrown: The question was very clearly edited after my comment. See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33699093/revisions .

Comment: @FelixKling The question may have been edited after your comment, but that was not clear from either your comment or the original poster's.

Comment: Yes, did edit to make it clearer. Apologies for the confusion in the original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably keep the data normalized and refer to the shared content by some sort of key, similar to how Java serialization works.